How can I update a bundled json file in a react native app locally from the app
I have a react native app that includes translation files in json format.
I have also a backend that serves the latest update of translation files and I merge the local with the remote and use it with i18next.
Once I merged the translation files, optimally, I would like to update the local json file with this merged file. Is it possible to change a bundle json file? If so, how?

No without codepush. Simply on device, update the local json file. What part do you not get?
